# Generate strings of random characters

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, random

I've a function to generate random characters from a set of alphabets. This function would be called multiple times and thus I'm trying to make it use same set of variables, i.e. have same seed so that strings don't repeat as long as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

std::string generateRandomChar(const unsigned int _len)
    {
        std::string result;
        result.reserve(_len);

        static constexpr char alphanum[] = "0123456789"
                                           "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                           "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);

        for (int i = 0; i < _len; 
            result += (alphanum[dis(gen)]);
        }
        return result;
    }

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        std::cout << generateRandomChar(10) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have any expertise with C++11 `<random>` functions and I was only using `srand` and friends earlier, so I might be making lots of mistakes here. Currently it works and generates tons of strings without repeating, but I'm sure I could make either of:

- `std::random_device rd;`
- `std::mt19937 gen(rd());`
- `std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 61);`

static variable too, so that it isn't calculated each time the function is called because that would be waste right?

So which one should be static here? Are there any mistakes/improvements that you see here?

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/e7ssXo)

Comment: I am not sure whether the fact that your output yields results that are unique if called multiple times (a low number of times I might add), is anything but the result of your rd, mt19937 and dis call.

So I think that making those static and not on a per call base is a bad plan.

Comment: @Quant I'm sorry I couldn't understand your suggestion. I'm no good with English language and it's quite long sentence. would you mind explaining it. I'm not guaranteeing uniqueness, but I'm trying to not regenerate multiple times if more common words are generated. For perfect uniqueness, I know there must exist one to one correspondence function but it won't be easy as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you place `static` will change the behaviour of your program tremendously. In the end, we have \$2^3 = 8\$ combinations, so let's check some of them.

A `random_device` may fall back to a pseudorandom engine if no hardware-device for random numbers is available. If you **don't** use `static` on `random_device` in this case, all your strings *may* end up the same, as the pseudorandom engine *may* get initialized with a implementation defined fixed seed, e.g.

```
 std::random_device a;
 std::random_device b;
 assert(a() == b());  // worst case if no hardware-device or a low-effort implementation is used
```

In this case, a `mt19937` would get seeded with the same value all the time, and we end up with the same string in every call. This changes if either `mt19937` or `random_device` is static, and *may* change if `dist` is static, as a `uniform_int_distribution` *can* use several calls to the generator for its internal state.

Of course, if `mt19937` is static, you may as well change `random_device` to a `static` variant, as it will get evaluated only once. This is the closest your get to a single `srand()` call at the start of your program. Your `uniform_int_distribution` still loses its internal state, though.

In the end, it depends on whether we want two `generateRandomChar` calls to correlate to each other. If they shall not correlate at all, we need to reseed our PRNG with a new non-deterministic number and cannot use `static` at all.

Or, to put it in another way: if we use `static` for *all* three values, then

```
generateRandomChar(10) + generateRandomChar(10)
```

is the same as
    generateRandomChar(20)
If we use `static` on `mt19937`, then both *may* be the same, depending on both `_len` and `dist`.

Either way, if you want to have more control over the generation, you can just provide a generator in your function:

```
template <typename Generator>
std::string generateRandomChar(Generator & gen, const unsigned int _len)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Same holds for the distribution.

---

Other than that, I'd use `sizeof` instead of `61` to make sure that I don't accidentally change the pool of possible characters without changing the number bounds in `dist`'s constructor:

```
static constexpr char alphanum[] = "0123456789"
                                   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                                   "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, sizeof(alphanum) - 1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create a separate wrapper class for this occasion. I used the following:

```
#include <random>
class randomStreamUniformInt {
public:
    explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound)
    : mt(rand()), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}
    explicit randomStreamUniformInt(int lower_bound, int upper_bound, double seed)
    : mt(seed), uniform_dist(lower_bound, upper_bound) {}

    int operator ()(void) { return uniform_dist(mt); }
private:
    std::mt19937_64                     mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<>     uniform_dist;
};
```

You can obviously extend it to use your prefered generator. Then you should either pass this per reference to your function or create a class with generateRandomChar as a method.